# Extract all data contained in a structure imported from BSgenome library

Tags: r, data-structures, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have extracted particular data of interest from `BSgenome` library but I am failed to export the data from its structure.

Here is the code

```
library(BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38)

genome = BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38
chr1 = genome$chr1
p1 = "ATC"
chrom1 = matchPattern(p1, chr1)
```

I want to save the data of *chrom1*, I have tried via *write.table* but not working.

if I print the c`hrom1[1:10]`, it gives me following result

```
     start   end width    
 [1] 10546 10548     3 [ATC]    
 [2] 11146 11148     3 [ATC]    
 [3] 11161 11163     3 [ATC]    
 [4] 11577 11579     3 [ATC]   
 [5] 11598 11600     3 [ATC]    
 [6] 11847 11849     3 [ATC]    
 [7] 12002 12004     3 [ATC]    
 [8] 12119 12121     3 [ATC]    
 [9] 12202 12204     3 [ATC]    
[10] 12247 12249     3 [ATC]
```

Like wise

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Ask questions about Bioconductor packages on the Bioconductor support site https://support.bioconductor.org

Answer (score 4):

Convert to *data.frame*:

```
as.data.frame(chrom1@ranges)
#    start   end width
# 1  10546 10548     3
# 2  11146 11148     3
# 3  11161 11163     3
# ...
```

As pointed out by @MartinMorgan in the comments we can avoid direct slot access using *methods::as()* function:

```
as.data.frame(as(chrom1, "IRanges"))
```

Comment: Almost never a good idea to use direct slot access; just `as.data.frame(as(chrom1, "IRanges"))`

Comment: @MartinMorgan Thank you, updated the post with your suggestion.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Could you please point me to some documents/manuals where `"direct slot access is a bad idea"` explained in detail?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `start`, `end` and `width` respectively.

```
df <- data.frame(start = start(chrom1), end = end(chrom1), width = width(chrom1))
#  start   end width
#1 10546 10548     3
#2 11146 11148     3
#3 11161 11163     3
#4 11577 11579     3
#5 11598 11600     3
#6 11847 11849     3
```

I'm not sure if this works for all `XStringsViews` classes, but you can try and add the `ATC` column by using:

```
df <- data.frame(start = start(chrom1), end = end(chrom1), width = width(chrom1), p1=BSgenome::as.data.frame(chrom1)[,1])
#  start   end width  p1
#1 10546 10548     3 ATC
#2 11146 11148     3 ATC
#3 11161 11163     3 ATC
# ...
```

Comment: Good to know about `start, end, width` functions, thank you. Any idea how would you get `"[ATC]"` column?

Comment: Other than a hacky solution that "seems" to work; `BSgenome::as.data.frame(chrom1)[,1]`, I have no clue